# Странное поведения php и Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Мое приложения отправляет запрос на создание публикации на мой api (php and database mysql). В api использую ORM систему RedBeanPhp для запросов в базу данных. Проблема такая что запрос приходит и создаётся публикация в базе данных и после этого в течении минут пять создаются еще пустые публикации (числа этих пустых публикаций рандомна. Когда 10, а когда 1). В базе данных полям даже поставил чтобы нигде null не был и все публикации поля должны быть заполнены, но нет. Не помогает. В чем может быть проблема? Может вы с такими проблемами встречались ранее? 

**U.D.P.** 
вот код скрипта апи который создает публикацию:

```
<?php



require 'function.php';



$path01 = naming();

$path02 = naming();

$path03 = naming();

$path04 = naming();



if (valid($_POST['data']))) 

{

    require 'rb.php';

    require 'connect.php';



    $object = json_decode($_POST['data']);



    $error = 0;

    if ($object->vip != "1" && $object->vip != 1) {

        $number = R::count( "publication", "`userid` = ? AND WEEK(`data`) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND `vip` = 0 ", [$object->id] );



        if ($number >= 2) {

            $error = 1;

        }

    }



    $creat = R::dispense('publication');

    $creat->userid = valid($object->id) ? $object->id  : 0;

    $creat->name = valid($object->name) ? $object->name : "default";

    $creat->location = valid($object->location) ? $object->location : "unknown";



    $price = valid($object->price) ? $object->price : "0";

    $creat->price = $price."TMT";

    $creat->kredit = valid($object->kredit) ? $object->kredit : 0;

    $creat->obmen = valid($object->obmen) ? $object->obmen : 0;

    $creat->phone_number = valid($object->phone_number) ? "+993".$object->phone_number : "unknown";

    $creat->other  = valid($object->other) ? $object->other : "yok";

    $creat->vip = valid($object->vip) ? $object->vip : 0;


    if (!empty($_POST['image_one']) && $_POST['image_one'] != "0" && $error != 1) {

        file_put_contents("../img/".$path01, $_POST['image_one']);

        $creat->image_one = $path01;

    }

    else{

        $creat->image_one = "0";

    }


    if (!empty($_POST['image_two']) && $_POST['image_two'] != "0" && $error != 1) {

        file_put_contents("../img/".$path02,    $_POST['image_two']) ;

        $creat->image_two = $path02;

    }

    else{

        $creat->image_two = "0";

    }


    if (!empty($_POST['image_three']) && $_POST['image_three'] != "0" && $error != 1) {

        file_put_contents("../img/".$path03,  $_POST['image_three']);

        $creat->image_three = $path03;

    }

    else{

        $creat->image_three = "0";

    }

    if (!empty($_POST['image_four']) && $_POST['image_four'] != "0" && $error != 1) {

        file_put_contents("../img/".$path04, $_POST['image_four']);

        $creat->image_four = $path04;

    }

    else{

        $creat->image_four = "0";

    }

    if($error != 1){

        $creat = R::store($creat);

    }

    echo json_encode(array('data' => "+99362891947 5" , 'error' => $error));

}

else

{

    echo "0";

}
```

Comment: очень сложно без вашего кода разобраться

Comment: @StereoFlo взгляните пожалуйста. Я изменил вопрос

Comment: Что первое приходит в голову - баг у вендора. Не сочтите меня занудой, но почему вы не исползуете `composer` ? Он же как минимум облегчит вам жизнь  хотя бы с теми же обновлениями библиотек.

Comment: @zalex этот api я написал до углубленного изучение php. Я даже фреймворков не знал и не умел пользоваться композерам. Сейчас же нет времени все переписовать.